Azure Java SDK getBlobsByTags gives AuthorizationPermissionMismatch Error
Using Azure Java SDK, We are trying to access Blob Storage entries from Azure Storage Account. We only want to Read the blob storage message. We don't have any requirement to write to it.
Our application has Storage Blob Data Reader access and Reader and Data Access.
blobclient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().endpoint("<endpoint>").credential(<valid credential>).buildClient();
System.out.println ("After getting blobclient");
blobcontainer = blobclient.getBlobContainerClient("<container name>");
System.out.println ("Got blob container");
PagedIterable<TaggedBlobItem> list = blobcontainer.findBlobsByTags("<valid query format>");
System.out.println ("After findblobbytags");
for (TaggedBlobItem blobItem : list) {
        System.out.println ("Inside for loop. Got blobItem");
        System.out.println("Blob name: " + blobItem.getName());
}

It is printing until findblobbytags. But at the for loop, get this error -
<Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:31679602-001e-00a0-4812-bd6c51000000
Time:2024-06-12T21:52:11.3001653Z</Message></Error>

I did read links about having role with this Azure RBAC action: Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/filter/action - to be able to do the filter action.
Is that the only cause? My doubt occurs because the findBlobsByTags method isn't failing with the error whereas, the iteration in loop is failing.
Any inputs would help! Thanks.


Azure Java SDK getBlobsByTags gives AuthorizationPermissionMismatch Error

According to this MS-Document,
You need Storage Blob Data Owner with data action of Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/tags/read to read the blob from Azure blob storage.
In my environment, after assigning the above RBAC role with data action and below code executed successfully.
Code:
        String endpoint = "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/";
        String containerName = "test";

        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient()
                .getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        
        PagedIterable<TaggedBlobItem> findBlobsByTags = blobContainerClient.findBlobsByTags("\"createdby\"='venkat'");{
            System.out.println ("After findblobbytags");
            for (TaggedBlobItem blobItem : findBlobsByTags) {
                System.out.println ("Inside for loop. Got blobItem");
                System.out.println("Blob name: " + blobItem.getName());

Output:
After findblobbytags
Inside for loop. Got blobItem
Blob name: sample-20240624-1429.txt
Inside for loop. Got blobItem
Blob name: testblob.txt


Reference:
BlobServiceClient Class | Microsoft Learn

Thanks Venkat for your response. I may not be given the Storage Blob Owner Role. Hence, trying to see if there can be a custom role created and the specific RBAC action be assigned to that role. Would you be able to check how the same code of yours behaves when you assign only "Storage Blob Data Reader" & "Reader and Data Access" to the calling application? Does it fail at findBlobsByTags or the for loop iterator line? If I did not have enough permissions, I would assume the method call itself will fail. But it doesn't seem to be the case for me.  Unable to connect that part. Thanks.

Please try this Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/tags/read rbac action in your custom role and try to execute the code.

Is the above approach worked for you?

Hi, Yes - we were able to get the Owner Role and it worked Thanks.

Do you know whether the findBlobsByTag return object will be null or empty when the query condition doesn't match? Or, will it throw an exception?

The findBlobsByTags method in the Azure Java SDK will return an empty PagedIterable<TaggedBlobItem> object if no blobs match the query condition. It does not throw an exception in this case.
